# Searching Indexing function not returning the value

Tags: java, actionscript-3

I want to search or select specific itmes from a list/array. So on constructing the function for searching in AS3 in flash, I got stuck..Please help to solve this problem...Thanks in advance

```
var ar:Array = new Array();
ar=[ "bhati", "malav", "vinod"];

//Searching Function
function findIndexOfValue( array:Array, _value:* ):int {
    var _length:uint = array.length;
    for(var i:uint=0; i < _length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == _value) {
            return i;
        }
        else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
}

trace(findInndexOfValue( ar, "bhati" )); // it should output 0 .
//compiler error:- 1170:Function doesn't return a value., I tried my best, but unable to solve this.
```

Answer (score 2):

Why bother with this? This functionality is built right into the Array class in AS3 (And most, if not all, OOP languages).

```
trace( this.ar.indexOf( "bhati" ) ); //will output 0
```

[Array#indexOf()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#indexOf%28%29)

As to why your script doesn't work, you have to return a value. You can't have all the returns in conditionals or loops. There must be a return in within the base level of the function.

EDIT: Just took a closer look at your function and there is more wrong with it than just the return. You will never make it beyond the first item in the array because it will always return a value (thanks to the else conditional). Simply remove the else bit and move the return in it to after the for loop runs and you will have a rough duplication of how indexOf works

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
function findIndexOfValue( array:Array, _value:* ):int {
    var _length:uint = array.length;
    for(var i:uint=0; i < _length; i++) {
        if(array[i] == _value) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```